# Xamarin Forms ListView Scroll position - MVVM

Tags: c#, listview, scroll, xamarin.forms

I'm searching about this article for weeks!

**UPDATE**

**Is controlling Listview scroll position in xamarin forms with MVVM pattern possible or not?** getting and setting the scroll position of listview.

There are some answers like implementing event aggregation or using messaging or ... .
Neither of them weren't operating for me. The messaging is not fully MVVM pattern way. The event aggregation didn't work even I'm using prism 7.
There is no such a good example code or any nuget package.

Has anyone encountered this problem and solved it?

Comment: Scrolling is enabled on ListView by default and it has nothing to do with MVVM pattern. What is your question?

Comment: not even sure what the question is, But the only reason why listview scroll is not working would be if you put listview inside scrollview. These two never go together

Comment: @EvZ Thank you for attention. I have updated the question. It was not completed.

Comment: @Luminous_Dev Thank you for attention. I have updated the question. It was not completed

Comment: What is wrong with `ScrollTo(..)` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.scrollto?view=xamarin-forms?

Comment: @EvZ you cannot use it in mvvm pattern, can you?

Comment: Why not? What have you tried? Please provide a specific problem with code that we could help you with.

Comment: @Evz give me a link, if you have any example, please :)

Comment: I provided you a link, explaining how to programmatically set the scroll position in `ListView`. Now, depends on your needs you could create "a bridge" between your V and VM layers. It can be done in different ways, including those that you already mentioned yourself. Unfortunately, Stackoverlow is not a coding service and if you want someone to help please share your code what have you tried already and please describe a specific problem. Currently it is just to broad.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178307/discussion-between-behzad-and-evz).

Answer (score 1):

CustomersViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<Customer> Customers {get;set;}
public Func<Customer,Task> ScrollToCustomer {get;set;}
public DelegateCommand FindBestCustomer {get;set;} // For example    
FindBestCustomer = new DelegateCommand(async() => 
{ 
    Customer bestCustomer = Customers.Last(); // this is our logic in view model!
    await ScrollToCustomer(bestCustomer);
    // at this time, scroll is finished.
});
```

---

CustomersView.xaml

```
<StackLayout>
    <ListView x:Name="CustomersListView" ItemsSource={Binding Customers} />
    <Button Text="Go to last customer" Command="{Binding ScrollToLastCustomer}" /> // For example
</StackLayout>
```

---

CustomersView.xaml.cs

```
override OnBindingContextChanged()
{
    if(BindingContext is CustomersViewModel customersViewModel)
    {
        customersViewModel.ScrollToCustomer = customer => CustomersListView.ScrollTo(customer);
    }
}
```

---

Comment: It's not an MVVM design pattern. You are using the code-behind.

Comment: You don't have any idea about mvvm. You want neither event aggregation nor messaging nor delegation! MVVM doesn't say you shouldn't have code behind at all. You might have some codes + some value converters and animations etc. As long as you respect separation of concerns, you're good too go! Let me know when you found a magic you're looking for. Thanks

Comment: @MarzieSagtarash +1 for your attention. I want all of them! But I couldn't implement event aggregation yet. I appreciate if you have any MVVM pastern for any of them. I'm trying to learn what you say :)